# How do I use qTip2 with CakePHP?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, qtip2

I can't seem to get qTip2 to work with Cake.

I'm using the following code, and while it does eliminate the existing title that would come up, it does not replace it with a qTip.  I have loaded the script and jquery of course.  Any thoughts?

```
<?php echo $this->Js->domReady ( "$('[title]').qtip();" ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use it on a `<title></title>` tag? This selector doesn't seem right. This is a CSS attribute selector `[title]` but it can't be used to attach JS events and functions to it.
All tooltip plugins use the `title` attribute for the generated tooltip, but you can't attach it like this.

You will need something like this:

```
$('title.tooltip').qtip();
```

if you're assigning this to `<title class="tooltip"></title>`. Check [this out on CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Comment: The selector is from the qtip 2 website.  I just assumed it was right.  I'll give that a try!